# Computing degree of similarity among a group of sets

Tags: metrics, similarity

Suppose there are 4 sets:

s1={1,2,3,4};
s2={2,3,4};
s3={2,3,4,5};
s4={1,3,4,5};

Is there any standard metric to present the similarity degree of this group of 4 sets?

Thank you for the suggestion of Jaccard method. However, it seems pairwise. 
How can I compute the similarity degree of the whole group of sets?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you want to do with your set of set similarity measure. Will you compare them to sets of more than 4 sets, or always 4? Are you trying to partition or cluster many sets?

Answer (score 9):

Pairwise, you can compute the [Jaccard distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_distance) of two sets. It's simply the distance between two sets, if they were vectors of booleans in a space where {1, 2, 3…} are all unit vectors.

Comment: +1, and probably the mean of the (6) Jaccard coefficients is what @Soup is looking for.

Comment: Seconding your idea of taking the mean.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very specific. But I suppose you mean something like the "edit distance" between them? I.e. how much you need to change s1 to get to s2?

Check out the Wikipedia article on [Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).

Answer (score 2):

As Tobu said I'd use the [Jaccard Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_distance) which is just the intersection divided by the union of the sets.

Answer (score 0):

you could compute the size of the intersection between each set

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distance_in_Euclidean_space) between them, and build a [dendrogram](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=79) from that to visualize similarity.